# Dark textures on Intel HD 3000 Sandy Bridge in games via Wine

Tags: wine, intel-graphics, games

Looks like I have some problem here. I'm trying to play some games on my notebook with Ubuntu 12.04. But all games I treed to play have dark textures. 2D objects (like menus and buttons) are NOT affected.

Example: http://imageshack.us/f/571/20120521122055.png/

Comment: Found bug https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48120 but it is about i965. I have i915 and solution dont make effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating graphics drivers, which is done by adding PPA repository. Most popular is Xorg-edgers, but this sometimes breaks system, because it influences on many components. I rather use OIBAF updated video drivers, which only updates graphics https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/ Read here more. And don't forget installing S3TC (libtxc-dxtn0), to use "patented" textures comression (this might be problem with black or missing textures)

Comment: I had the same problem reported by Undesired, and this solution helped just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your wine is up-to-date.

Copy and paste this on the Terminal:

```
export MESA_EXTENSION_OVERRIDE="-GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode -GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex -GL_ARB_map_buffer_range"
```

After that run the game using `wine game.exe`, where game.exe is your executable.

If you prefer, put this command in `.gnomerc` or `.profile` file in the HOME directory, so that you do not need to put this command every time you launch the game.

I'd had a similar problem with my Intel GMA4500 (Laptop too), and that fixed it.

PS: Make sure you have driconf installed `sudo apt-get driconf`, open it through the terminal and enable the S3TC texture compression.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem simply by switching to Kubuntu. It solved the 3stc rendering issue using its Plasma desktop - aimed at making 3-D games run better - and made a huge difference with LOLegends.